# Order of session_start, session_name, and session_set_cookie_params on WAMP

Tags: php, session, wamp

My development machine went down at work last week and I'm just getting it set back up. My predecessor had zend server running on windows, I went with WAMP as I was setting it back up. Our production servers are linux.

I checked out the codebase from SVN and got it all set up, only to find that sessions weren't working. The original session code that worked in zend and on linux looked like this:

```
$CookieConf = session_get_cookie_params();
$CookieConf["secure"]   = true;
$CookieConf["httponly"] = true;
session_set_cookie_params
(
    $CookieConf["lifetime"],
    $CookieConf["path"],
    $CookieConf["domain"],
    $CookieConf["secure"],
    $CookieConf["httponly"] 
);
session_name('Redacted');
session_start();
```

Some googling led me to believe that session_start should be called before other session methods, and sure enough moving session_start to the top of that block seemed to work. My sessions were persisting across page loads on both the dev server(wamp) and the test server(lamp).

Until I started to find particular functions that weren't working. Particularly on the login page, where I found that once the login was successful, it redirected to the account page, but the session data was lost in between. Now the account page thinks you're not logged in and sends you back to the login page. Which is really odd because I can't replicate the problem, seem to be able to redirect fine from other pages to the account page while saving session data, just this particular redirect that's not working.

So I dug into the man pages where the session_name page says:

> Thus, you need to call session_name() for every request (and before session_start() or session_register() are called).

So it looks like session_start should end that block of code like it was in the first place. But WAMP doesn't seem to like that.

Is this non-standard behavior on WAMP's part? How do I get my dev server to act like my production servers?

Comment: This seems odd, I suspect a configuration difference between the production and dev environments. I would compare the versions of PHP and possibly Apache on the two, then also compare all the session related variables in your php.ini files (or on a phpinfo() page) for clues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I downgraded my dev server til it matched my live server, but it didn't fix the problem. It turned out to be non-standard behavior on WAMP's part relating to the session cookie's lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue, turned out WAMP doesn't work right with the session cookie's lifetime set to 0. The man page for session_set_cookie_params() reads:

> session.cookie_lifetime specifies the lifetime of the cookie in seconds which is sent to the browser. The value 0 means "until the browser is closed." Defaults to 0.

The default of zero made me generate a whole new session id on each pageload, instead of persisting until the browser closed. Setting a cookie lifetime of 24 hours is a valid workaround for WAMP.